# What version is published online under "ahead of print" for an accepted paper?

Tags: publications, journals

Some journals publish the article online much before the publication, under the "ahead of print" section. My question is, will they send the proofs (to the author) before putting it in "ahead of print" itself, or only right before publication in print. What version will be published online under "ahead of print"?

Comment: May vary by journal, of course.

Comment: @Buffy : The proofs are sent only a month or fortnight before the publication in print (common practice). So If they wait for the proofs then the "ahead of print" is of no real advantage.

Comment: @user118656 That does not correspond with my experience. What makes you think that that is "common practice"?

Comment: perhaps I am wrong. But the journal assistant said they will send me the proofs a month before publication. and then they said that they would also inform the publisher to keep the article in "Ahead of Print" section online. I don't know whats really the advantage of this? just a month?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on journal policies. The one I'm most familiar with, the "ahead of print" articles are complete in every way except they've not been assigned to a volume & issue. If this is the case for you then of course they will send proofs to the author before putting it there.

Alternatively they can put the accepted manuscript there. If this is the case it will look *very* unpolished; it might not be in the journal's style, the figures might be on separate pages, and so on.

A glance at the articles already in the "ahead of print" section should reveal which is the case for you.

Comment: My experience agrees with this. After proofs have been corrected, the final version (except for volume and page numbers) is posted online, and no further changes are allowed for the printed version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes sense.